# Destructors output in C++

Tags: c++

The following code does not print "Destructor is called".  Why? However, my book prints it out. How to print the destructor statement? Please suggest.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HelloWorld
{
public:
  //Constructor
  HelloWorld()
  {
  cout<<"Constructor is called"<<endl;
  }
 
  //Destructor
  ~HelloWorld()
  {
   cout<<"Destructor is called"<<endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   //Object created
   HelloWorld obj;

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: At what point would you expect the output? You are pausing execution of everything with `system("PAUSE");` so you first need to continue from there

Comment: it  looks like u don't need that `system("PAUSE");`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
   { // start a scope
       //Object created
       HelloWorld obj;
   } // scope ends here, obj will be deleted here
  
   // now pause so you can see the output before program ends.
   system("PAUSE");

   return 0; 
}
```